# Invalid or corrupted file while compiling project included V8

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, static-libraries, embedded-v8

I've just compiled V8 as static libraries, everything compiled fine, but when I try to include thiese .lib files into my VS project - it says "Invalid or corrupted library" for v8_base_without_compiler.lib
I am on Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 2017, lastest SDKs

My GN build config:

`is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
is_component_build = false
v8_static_library = true`

If I need to provide more information - please inform me

Thank you!

```cpp
#include "Scripting.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "v8_base_without_compiler")
#pragma comment(lib, "v8_libbase")
#pragma comment(lib, "v8_external_snapshot")
#pragma comment(lib, "v8_libplatform")
#pragma comment(lib, "v8_libsampler")
#pragma comment(lib, "icuuc.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "icui18n.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "inspector")

VOID ScriptingJS::RegisterFunction() {
    V8::Initialize();
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Not the question author, but it definitely helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The lld linker is able to produce small lib files which contains indirection to the object files. That format is not supported by VS2017.

I had the same problem and solved it by using `use_lld = false` in my args.gn file (the build then use the VS2017 linker)